# Registering jQuery kills admin functions

Tags: wp-admin, jquery

I recently added the following into my theme's `functions.php`, in order to load jQuery from the CDN:

```
function my_init_method() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js');
}

add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
```

However, this causes problems with the admin screens, notably the WYSIWYG editor which then refuses to allow HTML mode (via the tab). I get an error:

```
jQuery is not defined
```

from the wp-admin/load_scripts.php file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> jQuery is not defined

This is because the Google CDN Jquery is not in no-conflict mode.  Use the following to make sure the included WordPress no-conflict jquery is used in admin.

```
if( !is_admin()){
   wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.4.2'); 
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: Any reason for putting strings into brackets?

Comment: missed one argument => `false, '1.4.2', false`, just say that cause for some theme jquery is in the footer